Prove uniqueness of cubic splines using Rolle's theorem (for natural conditions (type I) and clamped conditions (type 2))
I was trying to prove this but got stucked in the way, so I wondered if there was something else I should take into account, here's what I've got for the type I case:
Let $\Delta = \{a = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n = b\}$ be a partition of $[a, b]$.
Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two splines such that:
$$
S_1(x_i) = S_2(x_i) = y_i,
$$
$$
S_1''(a) = 0 = S_2''(a), \quad S_1''(b) = 0 = S_2''(b).
$$
Furthermore, for $i = 0, \dots, n$, we have:
$$
S_1(x_i) - S_2(x_i) = 0.
$$
On the interval $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$, with $S_1, S_2 \in \mathbb{P}_3$, let $P(x) = S_1(x) - S_2(x)$. Then:
$$
S_1(x_{i-1}) - S_2(x_{i-1}) = 0,
$$
$$
S_1(x_i) - S_2(x_i) = 0.
$$
By Rolle's theorem, there exists $c \in (x_{i-1}, x_i)$ such that:
$$
P'(c) = 0, \quad \text{implying } S_1'(c) - S_2'(c) = 0.
$$
If $i = 1$, we are working on the interval $[a, x_1]$, where additionally:
$$
S_1''(a) - S_2''(a) = 0.
$$
Summarizing, we have the following conditions:
$$
S_1(a) - S_2(a) = 0,
$$
$$
S_1(x_1) - S_2(x_1) = 0,
$$
$$
S_1'(c) - S_2'(c) = 0,
$$
$$
S_1''(a) - S_2''(a) = 0.
$$
But from these conditions I can't conclude that $P(x)=0, x \in [a,x_1]$, take for example the polynomial $Ax(x^2-1)$ and $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, so here I am...
Thanks for helping me!
EDIT:
Perhaps this could work:
By Rolle's theorem, there exists $c_i \in (x_{i-1}, x_i)$ such that:
$$
P'(c_i) = 0, \quad i = 1, \dots, n.
$$
$P$ is also a spline, so it has:
$$
4n - 3(n-1) = n + 3
$$
degrees of freedom.
On the other hand, by Rolle's theorem, we obtain $n+1$ additional constraints, which, together with the clamped or natural conditions, ensure that:
$$
P(x) \equiv 0.
$$
